# Checkbos seleccionados en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

de nuevo preguntando...

si quiero saber los checkbox que hay seleccionados en una tabla html...

```
("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
             alert($(this).val());
        });
```

hasta aquí todo bien...pero...
hay 4 tablas más...y evidentemente, me alerta de todos los checkbox marcados en todas las tablas...

como puedo saber los checkbox seleccionados SOLO en una tabla ???

algo asi:

```
("tabla1:input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                 alert($(this).val());
            });
```

Muchas Gracias..chavales....

Comment: puedes hacerlo mediante algun identificador en las tablas para que solo te traiga los checkbox que estén seleccionados pero que se encuentran en dicho elemento con el id suministrado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando el id de cada `<table></table>`.

Si no tienen puedes anexarles en la etiqueta el atributo id al elemento `<table>` y en la fraccion del código que tienes puedes anexarle al inicio el id a la sentencia.

Ejemplo

Tenemos el elemento table de la siguiente manera:

```
<table id="tableOne">...</table>
```

Ahora el jQuery lo ajustamos de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#tableOne input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    const checkbox = $(this);
    console.log(checkbox, checkbox.val());
});
```

Te comparto un ejemplo funcional como ejemplo, en este caso hemos creado 3 tablas todas cuentan con 3 registros.

1. En la tabla 1 le hemos colocado el id `tableOne`. Esta tabla tiene 2 registros con el checkbox en `checked`
2. En la tabla 2 le hemos colocado el id `tableTwo`. Esta tabla tiene 1 registro con el checkbox en `checked`
3. En la tabla 2 le hemos colocado el id `tableThree`. Esta tabla cuenta con los 3 registros en `checked`

Para el ejemplo obtenemos los checkbox de la tabla 1 con id `tableOne` e imprimimos en consola el id proporcionado a cada elemento obtenido y su respectivo valor:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // Obtenemos los checkbox que estan checked de una tabla especifica, en este caso tel que tiene el id="tableOne"
  $('#tableOne input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    const checkbox = $(this);
    console.log('Forma1', checkbox[0].id, checkbox.val());
  });

  // Forma obteniendo todas las tablas existentes y a cada una se le obtiene los checkbox que esten checked
  $('table').each(function() {
    const table = $(this);
    $('#' + table[0].id + ' input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      const checkbox = $(this);
      console.log('Forma 2', table[0].id, checkbox[0].id, checkbox.val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Tabla 1 -->
<table class="table" id="tableOne">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Checkbox</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne" checked>
      </td>
      <td>Description One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo">
      </td>
      <td>Description Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" checked>
      </td>
      <td>Description Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Tabla 2 -->
<table class="table" id="tableTwo">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Checkbox</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFour">
      </td>
      <td>Description Four</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFive">
      </td>
      <td>Description Five</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSix" checked>
      </td>
      <td>Description Six</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Tabla 3 -->
<table class="table" id="tableThree">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Checkbox</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSeven" checked>
      </td>
      <td>Description Seven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxEight" checked>
      </td>
      <td>Description Eight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxNine" checked>
      </td>
      <td>Description Nine</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

He editado la respuesta y se hanexa una segunda forma, en la cual consiste en obtener todas las tablas primero y obtener de cada taba los checkbox que están checked. Para ello se implementó el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
$('table').each(function() {
    const table = $(this);
    $('#' + table[0].id + ' input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        const checkbox = $(this);
        console.log(table[0].id, checkbox[0].id, checkbox.val());
    });
});
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, pero, como lo haría si solo me interesan los checkbox de una columna en concreto....

Comment: @Aldeano, creo que esta propuesta responde la pregunta tal como la formulaste y, si tienes más dudas que no incluiste en la publicación original, lo adecuado sería aceptar la respuesta y crear otra pregunta donde expongas todo el escenario desde el inicio.